# How to mount a dmg file in Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, mount, dmg-image

I need to mount a `.dmg` file on windows 7. *These are the disk image container files as are commonly used with Apple's OSX.*

What applications/utilities will do this? I know Daemon tools won't.

Comment: XP answer here, may work for windows7....http://filext.com/info/showthread.php?t=160&page=4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the dmg file to an ISO format, then mount the iso with the same software that converted it.

[Magic Iso](http://www.magiciso.com/FAQ/FAQ0011.htm)

Or convert it to iso on a MAC PC

dmg to iso

> hdiutil convert /path/imagefile.dmg -format UDTO -o /path/convertedimage.iso

iso to dmg

> hdiutil convert /path/imagefile.iso -format UDRW -o /path/convertedimage.dmg

[MAC source](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/09/convert-a-dmg-to-iso-and-convert-iso-to-dmg-on-mac/)

Comment: ended up using power iso which worked for me.

Comment: Yes, that is handy software. Now get digging in all those files!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Wikipedia page on DMGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image):

> In Windows, most dmg images can be opened using several other programs
>   such as Acute Systems TransMac, HFSExplorer, [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), UltraISO or
>   IsoBuster. MacDrive[9] can also mount simple dmg files as drives under
>   windows, but not sparse disk or encrypted dmgs.

I suggest you try [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) as you can use it for free and it's pretty solid software.

For any Linux users wondering about this, the same Wikipedia page states:

> In Linux and possibly other Unix flavors, most .dmg files can be
>   burned to CD/DVD using the program cdrecord or directly mounted to a
>   mountpoint (e.g. mount -o loop,ro -t hfsplus imagefile.dmg
>   /mnt/mountpoint).
>
> PowerISO is a proprietary, cross platform, Freeware CLI tool that runs
>   on Linux; it can convert most proprietary image formats to ISO, and
>   newer versions support .dmg.

Comment: 7zip will let you extract a dmg, but that's not the same as mounting. For instance if you wanted to perform data recovery on a disk image, then the dmg drive image must be mounted as a drive (if the software doesn't read dmg natively of course)

Comment: I used 7-zip to extract the dmg and it has left me with a hfs file and says it cannot open the file as [HFS] archive.

Answer (score 2):

HFSExplorer is the only prg I know of that will open a password protected MAC DMG on WindowsXP (or in Win7 with Windows XP Mode installed - doesn't work under straight Win7).

Comment: Can this mount a dmg as a drive? Looks like it might be able to..?

Comment: Thanks this helped me browse an old HFS DMG. Now I need to figure out how to convert it to HFS+ so I can mount it on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

What I do to mount DMG:

- Convert DMG to ISO format using [AnyToISO](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Images-Utils/AnyToISO-Converter.shtml) app (comes as free Lite version, Pro version also available)
- The resulting ISO (HFS+ formatted) can be easily mounted to Vmware/VirtualBox machine if it's running OS X. You can also burn this image under Windows.

Alternatively you can simply extract DMG with this tool. Works on Mac and Windows

Comment: Didn't work for me using an old HFS DMG that I can browse using HFSExplorer. Tried the win and mac versions and the resulting ISO was not mountable. My aim is to reach a HFS+ DMG I can mount in Monterey.

Comment: I also tried extract and it errors with "Original HFS is not supported" so I guess thats the reason the ISO didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To mount/manipulate the DMG without conversion, you could use HFSExplorer. It comes as freeware, and has a decent set of options and features. Since your working on Windows 7, 7-Zip is the only other option I see for your situation. Either way, however, it appears as though you would have to perform some form of conversion since you're using Windows to access the dmg disk image archive. Then, you could use a preferred program of your choice to mount the new, workable disk image. I would also suggest avoiding TransMac unless you're willing to invest in a paid option. The closest I've come to doing what you're asking about involved the use of a third-party fs driver from Paragon solutions, but it only appears to work with universal disk images like the ISO.

https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows-free/

With that said, I am sorry to say that some form of conversion may be required to get the image mounted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

[Altap Salamander](http://www.altap.cz/), IMHO the best file manager, also can dive into .dmg files and extract files.

Comment: extracting files may not be his ultimate goal, he did say he wanted to mount the disk image. Still, nice to have another option on the table.